# How can I invoke a member function using bracket notation?

Tags: javascript, object-literal

```
var objectliteral = {
    func1:fn(){},
    func2:fn(){},
    .................
    funcn:fn(){}
}
```

I know I can invoke methods from that object literal using dot notation this:

```
objectliteral.func1();
```

But I would like to do that using array notation like this:

```
objectliteral[func1]. .... something something......
```

How do I do that? I know I can use apply or call methods - but I'm still don't quite get how they work.

Can I just do this?:

```
objectliteral[func1].apply();
```

**RESOLUTION**

based on answers:

```
objectliteral['func1']()
```

is all I need.
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, do this:

```
objectliteral['func1']();
```

You can also use a dynamic name:

```
var myfuncname='func1';
objectliteral[myfuncname]();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
var objectLiteral = {
    func1: function() { alert('func1'); },
    func2: function() { alert('func2'); }
};

// This does the same thing...
objectLiteral['func1']();

// As this does
objectLiteral.func1();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
objectliteral['func1']();
```

Answer (score 1):

user `objectliteral["funct1"].apply()` or `objectliteral["funct1"]()`.

You can also use a variable to pass the function name

```
var funname = "funct1";
objectliteral[funname ]()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `objectliteral["func1"]();`

Answer (score 1):

```
var func1 = 'func1'
objectLiteral[func1]();
```

Should get you working.